# MongoDb SpringBoot update currentUser

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am creating a springBoot and angular 9 application and i am using MongoDb, for the authentication i am using springBoot jwt authentication, now i want to update the currentuser
Here is the Class user :

```
 @Document(collection = "users")
```

public class User {

```
@Transient
public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "users_sequence";
@Id
private Long id;
private String username;
private String email;
private String emailConfirmee;
private String password;
private String passwordConfirmed;
private String site;
private String presence;
private String avertirReponse;
private String avertirMisiive;
private String popup;

public User() {
}

public User(Long id, String username, String email, String emailConfirmee, String password,
        String passwordConfirmed, String site, String presence, String avertirReponse, String avertirMisiive,
        String popup) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.emailConfirmee = emailConfirmee;
    this.password = password;

    this.passwordConfirmed = passwordConfirmed;
    this.site = site;
    this.presence = presence;
    this.avertirReponse = avertirReponse;
    this.avertirMisiive = avertirMisiive;
    this.popup = popup;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmailConfirmee() {
    return emailConfirmee;
}

public void setEmailConfirmee(String emailConfirmee) {
    this.emailConfirmee = emailConfirmee;
}

public String getPasswordConfirmed() {
    return passwordConfirmed;
}

public void setPasswordConfirmed(String passwordConfirmed) {
    this.passwordConfirmed = passwordConfirmed;
}

public String getSite() {
    return site;
}

public void setSite(String site) {
    this.site = site;
}

public String getPresence() {
    return presence;
}

public void setPresence(String presence) {
    this.presence = presence;
}

public String getAvertirReponse() {
    return avertirReponse;
}

public void setAvertirReponse(String avertirReponse) {
    this.avertirReponse = avertirReponse;
}

public String getAvertirMisiive() {
    return avertirMisiive;
}

public void setAvertirMisiive(String avertirMisiive) {
    this.avertirMisiive = avertirMisiive;
}

public String getPopup() {
    return popup;
}

public void setPopup(String popup) {
    this.popup = popup;
}
```

}

UserRepository:

```
    @Repository
```

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
Optional findByUsername(String username);

```
Boolean existsByUsername(String username);

Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
```

}

AuthController :

```
public class AuthController {
@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
JwtUtils jwtUtils;

@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, userDetails.getId(), userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getEmail()));
}

@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Le nom de Combattant est déjà pris!"));
    }

    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("L'email est déjà pris!"));
    }

    // Create new user's account
    User user = new User(signUpRequest.getId(), signUpRequest.getUsername(), signUpRequest.getEmail(),
            signUpRequest.getEmailConfirmee(), encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()),
            signUpRequest.getPasswordConfirmed(), signUpRequest.getSite(), signUpRequest.getPresence(),
            signUpRequest.getAvertirReponse(), signUpRequest.getAvertirMisiive(), signUpRequest.getPopup());
    user.setId(SequenceGeneratorService.generateSequence(User.SEQUENCE_NAME));
    userRepository.save(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
}
```